# How to wait until an image is fully loaded in Java

Tags: java, image, concurrency

The Java image API assumes asynchronous loading. Various methods take an ImageObserver as a parameter which might get informed once the image is completely loaded.

On the other hand some types of images (e.g. BufferedImages) don't use the ImageObserver and will never call it.

So how would code look that waits until an image is fully loaded?

I'd like to have a method like

```
public void waitUntilLoaded(Image img){
    ...
}
```

Which guarantees that the image is completely loaded when it returns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good option would be `java.awt.MediaTracker`. There's a good code example [in the API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html).  In short, you create a MediaTracker object to track images for a component, tell it which images you want to track, and then call `tracker.waitForID(n)` which will block until the specified image has finished loading.

Obviously, you need to keep this out of the event thread--but you knew that.  :)

Comment: Looks like this is of no use either since I don't have a Component.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`javax.imageio.event.IIOReadProgressListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/event/IIOReadProgressListener.html) and override its [`imageComplete`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/event/IIOReadProgressListener.html#imageComplete%28javax.imageio.ImageReader%29) method instead of an `ImageObserver`.

This is assuming you can change the code to use a [`javax.imageio.ImageReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html) to actually read it (created using one of [`ImageIO`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)'s static methods).

Comment: I don't think I can use it. I'll get an Image from an unknown source and need to make sure that it is complete before starting my work

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative I found is to wait until `img.getWidth()` returns a value different from -1. You can do this in a cleaner way by using `Threads` and `while` loops.