# Java Swing ImageIcon not showing in JLabel

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, imageicon

As I found out the following [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) reproduces each time it is executed the same error:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class IconDelegate implements Icon {
    private final Icon delegated;

    public IconDelegate(final Icon delegated) {
        this.delegated = Objects.requireNonNull(delegated);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return delegated.getIconWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return delegated.getIconHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(final Component c, final Graphics g, final int x, final int y) {
        delegated.paintIcon(c, g, x, y);
        //Some other drawing operations would be here...
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon();
        final GraphicsEnvironment genv = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        final GraphicsDevice gdev = genv.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        final GraphicsConfiguration gcnf = gdev.getDefaultConfiguration();
        final BufferedImage bimg = gcnf.createCompatibleImage(300, 400);
        final Image img = bimg.getScaledInstance(150, 200, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        //img.getWidth(null); //Uncomment this line and the image will be drawn normally!
        ////img.flush(); //Uncomment this line and the image will not be drawn.
        ii.setImage(img);
        System.out.println(ii.getImageLoadStatus() == MediaTracker.ABORTED);
        final JLabel lbl = new JLabel(new IconDelegate(ii));
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("ImageIcon delegate.");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lbl);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The error, which I hope anyone can reproduce, is that the `ImageIcon`'s image is never drawn in the shown label/frame.

As I was trying to debug it, I found out that the *image load status* (of the `ImageIcon`) is equal to `MediaTracker.ABORTED` which delegates to `ImageObserver.ABORT` of the target `Component` (which implements `ImageObserver`) of the `MediaTracker` of the `ImageIcon` instance, which in turn (according to the documentation of `ImageObserver`) has to do with its `imageUpdate` method.

I also noticed that if I call `img.getWidth(null);` just before setting the image to the `ImageIcon` then the image is drawn normally (ie the error stops reproducing) and the image load status is *not* equal to `MediaTracker.ABORTED` anymore.
After reading the documentation of `ImageObserver.imageUpdate` method I've seen it states that the `Image.getWidth(ImageObserver)` method is *asynchronous*?...

I also noticed that if I call `img.flush();` after the `img.getWidth(null);` call, then the error reproduces.
Calling `img.getWidth(null);` after flushing the image stops the error from reproducing.
This pattern can be repeated.
As such, I come down to the probably most important piece of information I found in the documentation of `MediaTracker`:

> If no `ImageObserver`s are observing the image when the first frame has finished loading, the image might flush itself to conserve resources (see `Image.flush()`).

I have to note that I do care about the sequence of events. For example I need that the `ImageIcon` is created empty, and then use `setImage` to update its image.
I'm saying this because, as I noticed, creating the `ImageIcon` and supplying it with the image at construction time seems to draw the image correctly rather than reproducing the error.
After looking at the differences of the `ImageIcon`'s constructor which accepts an `Image` and the `ImageIcon.setImage` method I've seen that the constructor also requests the property '*comment*' from the image, supplying the `Image.getProperty` method with an `ImageObserver`... So I'm also guessing it's *asynchronous*?...

I've also called `System.out.println(img.getClass());` but it ended up in a class in the `sun.*` package with *compiled code* and no documentation. So I couldn't keep up.

I hope my efforts of debugging are not missleading.

So my questions are:

1. What causes the image to not been drawn in the MRE?
2. How to prevent this error from happening without having to make arbitrary calls (such as `img.getWidth(null);` before the `setImage`)?

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260500/how-to-wait-until-an-image-is-fully-loaded-in-java) related question, but I see that the `ImageIcon` class internally uses a `MediaTracker` so what's the point of repeating the code?
The reason why the `MediaTracker` of the `ImageIcon` aborts the loading of the image (according to its load status) is something I don't know.

### Edit 1

A more-realistic and less-minimal MRE which still reproduces the error is the following:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ImageThumbnail implements Icon {
    private final ImageIcon delegated;
    private final int w, h;
    private String text;

    public ImageThumbnail(final int width, final int height, final String text) {
        w = width;
        h = height;
        this.text = Objects.toString(text).trim();
        delegated = new ImageIcon();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return w;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return h;
    }

    public void setText(final String text) {
        this.text = Objects.toString(text).trim();
    }

    //Scales the given image to fit this icon's width and height maintaining aspect ratio:
    public void setImage(final BufferedImage bimg) {
        final int bimgw = bimg.getWidth(),
                  bimgh = bimg.getHeight();
        if (bimgw > bimgh)
            delegated.setImage(bimg.getScaledInstance(Math.min(w, bimgw), -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        else
            delegated.setImage(bimg.getScaledInstance(-1, Math.min(h, bimgh), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        //Alternatively you can try the following code if you don't trust the -1 arguments above:
        //delegated.setImage(bimg.getScaledInstance(w, h, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(final Component c, final Graphics g, final int x, final int y) {
        delegated.paintIcon(c, g, x, y);
        //Other drawing operations here, like drawing a String, at the center, over the ImageIcon:
        g.drawString(text, x + w / 2 - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(text) / 2, y + h / 2);
    }

    private static JPanel centered(final Component c) {
        /*Creating a JPanel with GridBagLayout and a single component
        in it, will layout the component in the center of the JPanel.*/
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.add(c);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

            final ImageThumbnail thumb = new ImageThumbnail(200, 200, "Select an image...");

            final JLabel lbl = new JLabel(thumb);

            final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
            chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);

            final JButton load = new JButton("Load image");
            load.addActionListener(e -> {
                if (chooser.showOpenDialog(load) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        thumb.setImage(ImageIO.read(chooser.getSelectedFile()));
                        thumb.setText("Image-001");
                        lbl.setForeground(Color.GREEN.darker());
                        //lbl.repaint(); //Not needed, as I call 'lbl.setForeground(Color.GREEN.darker());' above...
                    }
                    catch (final IOException iox) {
                        iox.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            final JPanel contents = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            contents.add(centered(lbl), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            contents.add(centered(load), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Thumbnail of images.");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(contents);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

I know I could use a `SwingWorker` at the button to load the image so as the user experiences no lag, but to make things simpler, I preferred to block the EDT for a little time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to prevent this error from happening without having to make arbitrary calls

With your original code I was getting a NPE.

The following seems to work. I now see a black image:

```
//final ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon();
…
//ii.setImage(img);
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon( img );
```

Edit:

I tried playing around with different approaches including making sure the label has an ImageObserver. Nothing worked for me.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class IconMRE extends JPanel
{
    private ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon( new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB) );
    private JLabel label1 = new JLabel( icon );

    public IconMRE()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout(20, 20) );

        label1 = new JLabel( icon );
        add(label1, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
        icon.setImageObserver( label2 );
        label2.setIcon( icon );
        add(label2, BorderLayout.LINE_END);


        JComboBox<Color>comboBox = new JComboBox<Color>();
        comboBox.addItem( Color.RED );
        comboBox.addItem( Color.GREEN );
        comboBox.addItem( Color.BLUE );
        add(comboBox, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        comboBox.addActionListener( (e) ->
        {
            Color background = (Color)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
            g2d.setColor( background );
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
            g2d.dispose();
//          image.getWidth(null);
            icon.setImage( image );
//          label1.repaint();
        });

        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(2);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("IconMRE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new IconMRE() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The only thing that worked was to force a repaint() on the label.

Comment: Yes it does work. But as I state in the question I would like to allocate an empty ImageIcon first, and then use `setImage`. Can it be done like this? I have to do it like this, because in the real code I have I dont pre-know the Image that will be used. It is loaded from a file after the user selects it. I would also like not to use a setter for the ImageIcon so as not to allocate a new ImageIcon instance each time. If what I am requesting is at all possible, let me know.

Comment: The image is supposed to be black/blank yes. In the real code I have, it would be replaced by a loaded image from a file.

Comment: Where are you getting the NPE? I am not. Is it the `img.getWidth(null);` statement?

Comment: *...It is loaded from a file after the user selects it.* -  I fail to see why it makes a difference whether you create the ImageIcon before or after you load the image. Your "loading method" should simply return an ImageIcon (instead of an Image) and then you set the Icon on your label. I get the NPE when the getWidth() statement is still commented out. It is in the JDK code that is invoked by the delegate.paintIcon(…) statement. When I uncomment the getWidth() statement it works correctly.

Comment: Basically the difference you are talking about is that the ImageIcon instance will accept many images throughout its life time. Besides, that's the point of the `ImageIcon.setImage` method.

Comment: It can be done with allocating new ImageIcons every time, you are wright. It can be done with many ways probably. But why can't it be done in this particular MRE with this sequence of events I state? If impossible, then yes I will do it like you said and accept the answer. I appreciate your effort and time, but I would like to wait and see if there will be answers to tell us why the MRE provided does not show the created image. I know this will require even more time to answer but I am also looking into it. I will not wait for too long, but I am also not in a hurry.

Comment: As for the NPE, I'm using JRE 1.8.0_241 and I am not getting one. Maybe somewhere inside `ImageIcon.paintIcon` lies the problem. I will also test drawing the `img` manually instead of using delegated ImageIcons.

Comment: I don't know how the internals of the JDK methods work, so I can't really offer more help. If you want more help then you need to post a proper [mre] that more resembles your real application. That is you need a frame with a JLabel and a JButton. The ActionListener for the button would display a JFileChooser to prompt for an Image. You would then read Image and update the ImageIcon. Only with code like this can we be sure you are solving a problem for the real situation by making sure code runs on the EDT and so on.

Comment: The first MRE posted cannot be less minimal. So because it's too minimal, I also now posted a second, more realistic and less minimal MRE with GUI updates at the EDT, to demonstrate the same problem in a more realistic situation.

Comment: An MRE should be done using JDK classes to make sure custom classes don't introduce an error. So your IconDelegate and ImageThumbnail classes are not needed. In any case I was playing around with my own MRE to try different things. Nothing worked. I would agree with you that there seems to be a bug in the JDK. You should be able to add an ImageIcon to multiple components. If the image changes in then the Icon should be repainted for all components. Seems like the ImageObserver logic is not notifying the components to repaint themselves.  No idea how to fix it. See MRE.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I must have done something wrong by misusing the ImageIcon's observer pattern then, or a library bug, I don't know. We'll see.